# Django doctests in views.py

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, doctest

The Django 1.4 [documentation on tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#writing-doctests) states:

> For a given Django application, the test runner looks for doctests in two places:
>
> - The `models.py` file. You can define module-level doctests and/or a doctest for individual models. It's common practice to put application-level doctests in the module docstring and model-level doctests in the model docstrings.
> - A file called `tests.py` in the application directory -- i.e., the directory that holds models.py. This file is a hook for any and all doctests you want to write that aren't necessarily related to models.

Out of curiosity I'd like to know why Django's testrunner is limited to the doctests in `models.py`, but more practically I'd like to know how one could expand the testrunner's doctests to include (for example) `views.py` and other modules when running `manage.py test`.

I'd be grateful for any input.

Thank you.

Brian

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this by adding/editing the suite() function in tests.py which defines what tests will be run by the django test runner.

```
import unittest
import doctest
from project import views

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(doctest.DocTestSuite(views))
    return suite
```

Then just run your tests as usual and you should see your doctests in views.py run.

```
$ python manage.py test project
```

This is described in more detail in the [django testing documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/)

> When you run your tests, the default behavior of the test utility is to find all the test cases (that is, subclasses of unittest.TestCase) in models.py and tests.py, automatically build a test suite out of those test cases, and run that suite.
>
> There is a second way to define the test suite for a module: if you define a function called suite() in either models.py or tests.py, the Django test runner will use that function to construct the test suite for that module. This follows the suggested organization for unit tests. See the Python documentation for more details on how to construct a complex test suite.

However, keep in mind that constructing your own test suite means that the django test runner will not automatically run any tests you have in tests.py.  You'll have to add these into your suite manually, for example

```
import unittest
import doctest
from project import views

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFoo(self):
        self.assertEquals('foo', 'bar')

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(doctest.DocTestSuite(views))
    suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(FooTestCase))
    return suite
```

Comment: Is this still the correct way, with Django 1.8? Andre Miras's answer below suggests it has been updated.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Not sure about 1.8 but in 1.6 it appears to me that `suite()` is no longer called. Andre's answer with `load_tests()` worked instead.

Answer (score 19):

Things have [changed in Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner):

> Doctests will no longer be automatically discovered. To integrate
>   doctests in your test suite, follow the [recommendations in the Python
>   documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#unittest-api).

So all I had to do myself was (in my_app/tests.py):

```
import unittest
import doctest
from my_app import views

def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(views))
    return tests
```

Comment: At the end of my application tests.py file (I've updated my answer).

Comment: This worked for me thanks. I was able bring in the app's models rather than views for doctesting. And I think you can skip importing `unittest`?

Comment: This is the up-to-date answer. Also nice to note that it executes alongside normal TestCase tests, so no need to additionally use unittest.TestLoader or something similar to load more traditional django tests

Answer (score 8):

This is my `tests/__init__.py` implementation, based on [Jesse Shieh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380527/django-doctests-in-views-py/3030065#3030065):

```
import doctest
import unittest

list_of_doctests = [
    'myapp.views.myview',
    'myapp.forms.myform',
]
list_of_unittests = [
    'sometestshere',  # This file is myapp/tests/sometestshere.py
    'moretestshere',  # This file is myapp/tests/moretestshere.py
    'myapp.tests.othertest',  # Absolute paths also work.
]

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for t in list_of_doctests:
        suite.addTest(doctest.DocTestSuite(
            __import__(t, globals(), locals(), fromlist=["*"])
        ))
    for t in list_of_unittests:
        suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(
            __import__(t, globals(), locals(), fromlist=["*"])
        ))
    return suite
```

Basically, this solution allows adding arbitrary "files" (actually, modules) to the test suite. It allows splitting the unit tests into separate files, and allows adding any module that contains doctests. Just add the module names to the appropriate list at the top of this file.

Answer (score 5):

Use nosetests with plugin for django (django-sane-testing or django-nose) and use the [--with-doctest flag](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/doctests.html#cmdoption--with-doctest).

Answer (score 2):

I posted a github gist that lets you run test in any file or module in your project.
[Running doctests from specific modules and files](http://dodrum.blogspot.com/2011/01/running-doctests-in-django-project.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write your own `testrunner` and see, if you can include other files to be checked for doc tests.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#defining-a-test-runner

Answer (score 1):

Django's native testing system is based on `unittest` package. So it is not as powerful as it can be.

I recommend you using [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/) that is backward-compatible `unittest` on steroids. Use it along with [Django test runner that uses nose](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose). You can customize nose in many ways including pointing it to custom test locations using `-m` flag.