# Set testing options while django doctesting

Tags: python-3.x, django, testing, doctest

Following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024322/3719101) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030065/3719101), I have managed to run my doctest within django with:

```
# myapp/tests.py

import doctest
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite())
    return tests
```

Then running:

```
python manage.py tests
```

---

However, since I am used to test my (non-django) scripts with the simple command:

```
py.test --doctest-modules -x
```

I am now quite confused about:

- testing procedure not stopping after first failure (my good'ol `-x`) (so I get flooded with results and I need to scroll back all the way up to the first problem each time)
- option `# doctest: +ELLIPSIS` not being set by default.

How do I set this kind of options from this django `load_tests()` hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've got it. [Options flags](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#doctest-options) like `ELLIPSIS` or `FAIL_FAST` can be
provided as an `optionflags` argument to [DocTestSuite](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#doctest.DocTestSuite).

The right way to combine them, as reported [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#doctest.set_unittest_reportflags), is to [bitwise OR](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#bitwise) them :)

So the following does work:

```
# myapp/tests.py

import doctest
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(
                optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS | doctest.FAIL_FAST))
    return tests
```